# dynamic query convert into normal query

Tags: java, reactjs, angular

How to correct this condition when I use in where condition

```
AND 1=(CASE WHEN @ClientId>0 AND PartyID=@ClientId THEN 1
        ELSE 
            CASE 
                WHEN @ClientType=0 THEN 0 
                WHEN @ClientType=1 AND CountryID=121 THEN 1 
                WHEN @ClientType=2 AND NOT CountryID=121 THEN 1                 
                WHEN @CountryId>0 AND P.CountryID=@CountryId THEN 1 
                WHEN @ClientGroup>0 AND P.GroupID=@ClientGroup THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
            END
            END
```

this condition convert into case statement

```
If Not cmbClient.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
      QSTr1 = QSTr1 & " and PartyID=" & Math.Abs(cmbClient.SelectedValue)
    Else
      If cmbClientType.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        QSTr1 = QSTr1 & " and CountryID=121"
      ElseIf cmbClientType.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        QSTr1 = QSTr1 & " and not CountryID=121"
      End If
      If Not cmbCountry.SelectedIndex = -1 Then QSTr1 = QSTr1 & " and P.CountryID=" & cmbCountry.SelectedValue
      If Not cmbClientGroup.SelectedIndex = -1 Then QSTr1 = QSTr1 & " and P.GroupID=" & cmbClientGroup.SelectedValue
    End If
```

Please help me to correct this condition using case statement

Comment: Please use code blocks and format your code for better readability. As is this is rather unreadable.